# Excel Subtraction from Baseline

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I get Excel to subtract the baseline number (first number in the column) and the most recent value entered?

In my first column I will have a baseline number. What I want is for excel to subtract subsequent values from that baseline. For example, I want C2 - D2. However, if I enter a number in E2, I want it to be C2-E2. The number in the change column should be the baseline value minus the most recent value entered.

For example, in my first row I would want the value in the change column to be 30-12. But in the second row, it should be 25-20 because there aren't any values in E3 or F3. Hopefully that makes sense!

[image: excel example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the last number

```
=C2 - INDEX(C2:F2,MATCH(1E+99,C2:F2))
```

The MATCH returns the relative location of the last number to the INDEX.

[image]

Comment: What does the `1E+99` do? Is that basically infinity, and since infinity isn't a single number, it effectively looks for *any* number?

Comment: @BruceWayne it is not infinity but 1 with 99 `0`s after it.

Comment: I could have used `10^98` and gotten the same result @BruceWayne

Comment: Just because that number is so large, Excel just says "look up this super large number, but it's huge, so just find any number"?  Edit: Mainly I'm curious why that works, but using a wildcard (`"*"`) doesn't.

Comment: Not really,  rememeber that the default MATCH does not look for an exact match.  It looks for where the number is larger than one and smaller than the next.  So if I did: `MATCH(42,{10,30,20,40,50})` it will return `4`, but if I did `MATCH(42,{10,30,20}) it would return 3.  So we know that it will never find a cell that is larger than that impossibly large number it returns the last. as that is slot in which if fits. @BruceWayne